# Passing external parameters to live templates

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm, live-templates

I think I've found a use case that's at the halfway point between file templates and live templates. I'd like to use live templates for the extra functionality they provide, but still be able to access the parameters specified on file creation, as you can in file templates. Let me be more specific, suppose I have the following file template, with the extension "controller.js":

```
angular.module('${Module_name}').controller('${NAME}Ctrl', function() {
});
```

Now if I create a new file with this template, it will ask for a file and module name. I enter "test" and "myModule", respectively, which will create a "test.controller.js" file with the following contents:

```
angular.module('myModule').controller('testCtrl', function () {
});
```

So far so good, but what if I would like to have the controller name be a capitalized version of the name? Or have the injectables be a parameter the user can specify right off the bat, and move the cursor inside the controller definition immediately? A live template can do all of that just fine (imagine that the variables are set up accordingly):

```
angular.module('$moduleName$').controller('$controllerName$Ctrl', function($injectables$) {
  $END$
});
```

...except now, there's no way to access the ${NAME} parameter. The built-in fileNameWithoutExtension() function almost works, but that returns "test.controller" in this case.

Is there some way to get around this?

Comment: to me, fileNameWithoutExtension() function returns exactly what it is expected to return - file name without extension. What is "test.controller" ?

Comment: related ticket: [IDEABKL-6817](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-6817)

Comment: @lena: There's a bit of a trick with the file template, it has its extension set to "controller.js". The point of this is to indicate the type of an item in the filename. Now, if I type "test" in the popup when creating a new file, the resulting file will be name "test.controller.js". And that's why fileNameWithoutExtension() returns "test.controller" in this case: it only removes the last segment. It could interpret things either way, so this behaviour is fine, IMO, but it would have been a sort of workaround.